# Azure function, App registration, certificate - New-PnPTenantSite : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: azure, office365, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to create a Azure function to provisioning different kind of sites.

I've created a App in Azure AD and granted the app sharepoint and graph.

When connecting to the site I use a certificate but I'm unable to create new sites.

```
New-PnPTenantSite -Url $url -Title $LinkTitle -Description $description -Template "STS#0" -Owner $username -TimeZone 4 -Lcid 1044 -Force
```

error:

> New-PnPTenantSite : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

it returns site and lists if I use get-pnplist and get-pnpsite ..

Connect using this command:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -CertificatePath .\certkeyname.pfx -Tenant 'xxx.onmicrosoft.com' -ClientId 'xxxx-xxx-xx-xx-xxxxxxx' -Url 'https://xxx.sharepoint.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

answer is in this post
[Azure AD application with Global Administrator rights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42819826/azure-ad-application-with-global-administrator-rights)

> You can elevate the level of access an Application has in your tenant by adding the service principal of that application to the Company Administrator Directory Role. This will give the Application the same level of permissions as the Company Administrator, who can do anything. You can follow these same instructions for any type of Directory Role depending on the level of access you want to give to this application.
>
> Note that this will only affect the access your app has in your tenant.
>
> Also you must already be a Company Administrator of the tenant to follow these instructions.
>
> In order to make the change, you will need to install the Azure Active Directory PowerShell Module.
>
> Once you have the module installed, authenticate to your tenant with your Administrator Account:
>
> Connect-MSOLService
> Then we need to get the Object ID of both the Service Principal we want to elevate, and the Company Administrator Role for your tenant.
>
> Search for Service Principal by App ID GUID:
>
> $sp = Get-MsolServicePrincipal -AppPrincipalId 
> Search for Directory Role by Name
>
> $role = Get-MsolRole -RoleName "Company Administrator"
> Now we can use the Add-MsolRoleMember command to add this role to the service principal.
>
> Add-MsolRoleMember -RoleObjectId $role.ObjectId -RoleMemberType ServicePrincipal ->RoleMemberObjectId $sp.ObjectId
> To check everything is working, lets get back all the members of the Company >Administrator role:
>
> Get-MsolRoleMember -RoleObjectId $role.ObjectId
> You should see your application in that list, where RoleMemberType is ServicePrincipal >and DisplayName is the name of your application.
>
> Now your application should be able to perform any Graph API calls that the Company >Administrator could do, all without a user signed-in, using the Client Credential Flow.